# Android Studio Retrieve file from URL and parse contents

Tags: android, kotlin, url, text

I cannot for the life of me how to figure out the most simple task of retrieving a text file from a url and reading its contents. All the code I find is 5-12 years old and doesn't work. Since android api 30+ any network request on main thread give a android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException.
I'm stuck using kotlin for this portion.

I cant use DownloadManager (unless there is a way to store the file temporarily and retrieve contents) as the file doesnt need to be downloaded to the local storage only read.
The closest ive seen is from:
[Android - How can I read a text file from a url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38372571/android-how-can-i-read-a-text-file-from-a-url)

```
try {
// Create a URL for the desired page
URL url = new URL("mysite.com/thefile.txt");

// Read all the text returned by the server
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(url.openStream()));
String str;
while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
    // str is one line of text; readLine() strips the newline character(s)
}
in.close();
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
} catch (IOException e) {
}
```

But this code doesn't work.

Comment: `NetworkOnMainThreadException` For the rest the code looks ok.

Comment: Its in Java and the java -> kotlin converter is failing on while ((str = in.readLine()) != null) {
    // str is one line of text; readLine() strips the newline character(s)
}

Comment: "All the code I find is 5-12 years old and doesn't work" -- many books and courses on Android app development cover making HTTP requests, such as Web service calls. For example, I cover that subject in [this free book](https://commonsware.com/Jetpack) and [this free book](https://commonsware.com/AndExplore).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So after 3 days of wanting to jump off a cliff. I found the answer. Of course it was a few minutes after asking the question here (first question ever so be kind.). The only Issue is you need a SSL cert for HTTPS on the server retrieving the file. My server is http but i can get a cert in there and fix that. to Test i threw up a github repository and linked to the raw text file. Here is my solution if this saves you 3 days pour one out for me.

```
Thread {
            try {
                val url = URL("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/USERNAME/NeedHTTPSdontWanaSSL/main/info.txt")
                val uc: HttpsURLConnection = url.openConnection() as HttpsURLConnection
                val br = BufferedReader(InputStreamReader(uc.getInputStream()))
                var line: String?
                val lin2 = StringBuilder()
                while (br.readLine().also { line = it } != null) {
                    lin2.append(line)
                }
                Log.d("The Text", "$lin2")
            } catch (e: IOException) {
                Log.d("texts", "onClick: " + e.getLocalizedMessage())
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
        }.start()
```

Credit:
answered Aug 12, 2018 at 9:29
Aishik kirtaniya
[Android - How can I read a text file from a url?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38372571/android-how-can-i-read-a-text-file-from-a-url)

Comment: And this solves an android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException?

Comment: Yeah its calling a new Thread not running on the GUI/Main thread i beleive since it works for me. the Thread's description is "Allocates a new Thread object. This constructor has the same effect as Thread (null, target, gname), where gname is a newly generated name. Automatically generated names are of the form "Thread-"+n, where n is an integer."

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
import java.net.URL

val s = "https://www.someplace.com/dir/file.txt"
val text = URL(s).openStream().readAllBytes().decodeToString()
```

Wrap it in some exception handling if you want. So long as you don't keep references to the intermediate stream, it'll immediately be eligible for garbage collection. The stream will be closed when it's garbage collected, thus I don't bother with adding a call to explicitly close it.